# Viewing fixed page layout on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, fixed-width, page-layout

I am using fixed page layout of my website (http://www.oatmeeel.com). It works fine on desktop browsers but not on mobile devices. The website is scaled to fit the browser but the format of some components change. Help please? Thank you!

Comment: "A pint can't hold a quart" - Margaret Deland  -  springs to mind. You need to modify the layout according to the device

Comment: Thank you for such deep quote. But I would like the layout to be exactly the same, just minimized to fit the smaller screens, with everything looking identical to the desktop.

Comment: You cannot - screen is too small. That is why companies invest in creating web sites for mobile devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert all you fix width Containers to percentage. You anyhow want you website to fit to screen. So, instead of using the

```
width: 1442.88px;
```

which you are using. Covert this to 100%. And also, create percentage layout (fluid layout) for the website.
You might also need to use "media queries" to rearrange the elements if needed.

Look for these two terms:

***Percentage Layout(Fluid Layout)*** ***&*** ***Media Queries***.

You'll be on your way to fix the issue you are facing.
Still if you want any specifics, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough draft of what I use on most my responsive web design projects I start from scratch:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
<style>
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
@media (min-width: 728px) and (max-width: 1150px) {
/* enter large tablet style overrides here */
}
@media (min-width: 420px) and (max-width: 727px) {
/* enter medium tablet and large phone style overrides here */
}
@media (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 419px) {
/* enter small devices and phone style overrides here */
</style>
</head>

<body>
Website body here
</body>

</html>
```

The < meta name="viewport" .. > line in the < head > makes your responsive page look normal on mobile devices. Without it, your website looks zoomed way out on a mobile device and text gets hard to read.